# FailIfMissing" for SQLite ODBC driver

Tags: c#, sqlite, odbc

Using Visual Studio 2019 and SQLite3 with:

- System.Data.SQLite.dll .NET wrapper (available [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)), or
- SQLite ODBC driver (available [here](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/))

Both work well, but the syntax for "FailIfMissing" is not clear for the ODBC driver. This features allows you to specify a new, blank database should (or should not) be created if the target database is missing.

For the SQLite .NET wrapper, the connection string works:

```
"Data Source=C:\\path\\to\\MyDB.db;Version=3;FailIfMissing=True;"
```

But the equivalent connection string for ODBC is not working (a blank database is created):

```
"Driver=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\\path\\to\\MyDB.db;FailIfMissing=True;"
```

How do you prevent a new, blank database from being created with the ODBC driver?

Comment: I guess that's outside the obvious `File.Exists`, right? You want it done through the driver / connection string , right?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods: Yes, that's correct. The connection string should (or should not) enable the "FailIfMissing" feature of SQLite. This works correctly using the SQLite .NET wrapper, but the syntax is not working (and unclear if even supported) using the ODBC driver. Thanks.